# how to add a custom meta dynamic tag in all page using a module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, meta-tags

i want to make a module which will add a custom meta tag which will be dynamic as per page .it will appear in all page.
 [image]

i want this to be appear after meta name "viewreport".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about add meta after meta name "viewreport", But you can add dynamic like adding below code into default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="test.phtml" after="-"/>            
</referenceContainer>
```

OR

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="test.phtml" after="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

OR

```
<referenceBlock name="head.additional">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="test.phtml" after="-"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks.i have used "head.additional" but it placing my tag at the last of head but i want to add a meta tag though phtml at upper portion like before or after meta keyword,description, etc.